# HybridAuth widget doesn't appear on Drupal website

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, drupal-7, hybridauth

After installing the HybridAuth module, I configure the module for 3 social service providers including Facebook, Twitter and Google.

My problem is that I could not display the Hybrid widget for these 3 providers.

Does anyone got the same problem? I have attached the screenshot below.
[image: Configuration in admin panel] 
Configuration in admin panel

[image: Enabled this Hybrid widget in Block]
Enabled this Hybrid widget in Block

[image: Homepage - the Hybrid widget isn't there]
Homepage - the Hybrid widget isn't there

Please help!!

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you haven't set the permission for HybridAuth module. You can go to:

Modules=>HybridAuth=>Permissions=>HybridAuth

Then check the "anonymous users". Logout and refresh the page, you should be able to see the HybridAuth widget.